# Задача нахождения оптимального пути между этажами

Tags: c++, алгоритм, поиск, поиск-пути

Есть следующая задача:
У Кати насыщенный день на работе. Ей надо передать n разных договоров коллегам. Все встре- чи происходят на разных этажах, а между этажами можно перемещаться только по лестничным пролетам — считается, что это улучшает физическую форму сотрудников. Прохождение каждого пролета занимает ровно ﻿﻿11﻿﻿ минуту.

Сейчас Катя на парковочном этаже, планирует свой маршрут. Коллег можно посетить в любом порядке, но один из них покинет офис через ﻿﻿tt﻿﻿ минут. С парковочного этажа лестницы нет — только лифт, на котором можно подняться на любой этаж.

В итоге план Кати следующий:

Подняться на лифте на произвольный этаж. Считается, что лифт поднимается на любой этаж за ﻿﻿00﻿﻿ минут.
Передать всем коллегам договоры, перемещаясь между этажами по лестнице. Считается, что договоры на этаже передаются мгновенно.
В первые ﻿﻿tt﻿﻿ минут передать договор тому коллеге, который планирует уйти.
Пройти минимальное количество лестничных пролетов.
Помогите Кате выполнить все пункты ее плана.

Формат входных данных:
В первой строке вводятся целые положительные числа ﻿﻿nn﻿﻿ и ﻿﻿tt﻿﻿  ﻿﻿(2\leq n,t \leq 100)(2≤n,t≤100)﻿﻿  — количество сотрудников и время, когда один из сотрудников покинет офис (в минутах). В следующей строке n чисел — номера этажей, на которых находятся сотрудники. Все числа различны и по абсолютной величине не превосходят 100. Номера этажей даны в порядке возрастания. В следующей строке записан номер сотрудника, который уйдет через t минут.

Формат выходных данных:
Выведите одно число — минимально возможное число лестничных пролетов, которое понадобится пройти Кате.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n;
  int t;
  cin >> n >> t;
  vector<int> floors;
  int buf;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> buf;
    floors.push_back(buf);
  }
  int leave;
  cin >> leave;
  int leaveFloor = floors[leave - 1];
  int maxFloor = floors[n - 1];
  int minFloor = floors[0];
  int result = 0;
  if (leaveFloor > t && (maxFloor - leaveFloor) > t) {
    int timeAfterStartFloor = 0;
    if (maxFloor - leaveFloor >= leaveFloor - minFloor) {
      timeAfterStartFloor = leaveFloor - minFloor;
      result += timeAfterStartFloor;
    } else {
      timeAfterStartFloor = maxFloor - leaveFloor;
      result += timeAfterStartFloor;
    }
  }
  result += floors[n - 1] - floors[0];
  cout << result << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Вопрос: Что не так с решением? не проходит тесты(

Comment: Был этот вопрос недавно от ваших однокашников, а вы даже не поискали.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%A3+%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос словестное описание вашего решения. Как именно следует действовать Кате?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да, я находил эту же задачу здесь, однако то решение так и не прошло. Поэтому я решил еще раз описать этот вопрос

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Если словами, то нужно сначала проверить, возможно ли успеть до уходящего человека с начального этажа и с конечного. Если нет, то нужно сначала на лифте ехать к нему. А потом решить, куда возвращаться, в начало или в конец. И далее проходить по всем этажам

Answer (score 0):

Пример:

> ```
> n = 3;
> t = 1;
> этажи 10, 11, 13;
> уходящий сотрудник 2.
> ```

Ваша программа решит что надо ехать на 11 этаж, спуститься на 10, подняться на 13 - всего четыре этажа.

Правильное решение - ехать на 10, подняться на 13 - три этажа.

Ошибка в условии `leaveFloor > t` - нет смысла сравнивать абсолютные номера этажей с чем бы то ни было. Значение имеют только разницы между номерами этажей: `leaveFloor - minFloor > t`.

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе нужен код чуть проще, чтобы разобраться, то прикреплю его ниже:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, t, man;
    cin >> n >> t;
    int nums[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cin >> nums[i];
    cin >> man;
    if (man == 1 || man == n || min(nums[man - 1] - nums[0], nums[n - 1] - nums[man - 1]) <= t)
        cout << nums[n - 1] - nums[0];
    else
        cout << min(nums[man - 1] - nums[0], nums[n - 1] - nums[man - 1]) + nums[n - 1] - nums[0];
}
```

**Объяснение:**

1. В случаях, когда данный нам сотрудник располагается на первой или последней позициях, или расстояние между первой позицией и позицией сотрудника или расстояние между последней позицией и позицией сотрудника не превосходит `t`, то мы можем пройти все этажи разом (либо сверху вниз, либо снизу вверх);
2. Если же ни одно из этих условий не выполнено, то логично будет сразу же подняться на этаж данного нам сотрудника и дойти до того этажа (первого или последнего), который ближе к этажу этого сотрудника, так как мы будем потом проходить абсолютно все этажи, чтобы дойти до другого конца этажа (первого или последнего).